# Why I'm getting small score of correlation and mutual information?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, pearson-correlation

I'm generating random samples for binary classification problem:

```
X, y = make_classification(n_features=40, n_redundant=4, n_informative=36,n_clusters_per_class=2, n_samples=50000)
```

I want to check the correlation between the features and the target (for `feature selection` step).

I'm using 2 different methods:

```
1. correlation (pearson)
2. mutual information
```

I'm getting small score, for both methods between the features and the target.

Mutual information:

```
    from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
    res1 = mutual_info_classif(X, y)
```

Correlation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=X)
df['Taregt'] = y
res2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.corr(df['Taregt']))
```

For both methods I'm getting results which are less than 0.4

Why am I getting small score ? I expect to get higher score ? 
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an artificially generated random classification dataset, made by the convenience function `make_classification` of scikit-learn. There is absolutely no reason to expect that there will be any particular value range for the correlation coefficients between the features and the label. In fact, a simple experiment shows that there is indeed a range of correlation values, going as high as ~ 0.65 (positive or negative) and as low as about zero, as expected in such **random** data; keeping `n_features=10` for brevity::

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.feature_selection import mutual_info_classif
import pandas as pd

for i in range(10):
  X, y = make_classification(n_features=10, n_redundant=4, n_informative=6,n_clusters_per_class=2, n_samples=50000)
  df = pd.DataFrame(data=X)
  df['Target'] = y
  res2 = df.apply(lambda x: x.corr(df['Target']))
  print(res2)
```

Result:

```
0        -0.299619
1         0.019879
2        -0.271226
3         0.324632
4        -0.299824
5         0.277574
6         0.028462
7         0.395118
8         0.297397
9         0.001334
Target    1.000000
dtype: float64
0        -0.008546
1        -0.131875
2         0.009582
3         0.314725
4         0.292152
5         0.002754
6         0.203895
7         0.009530
8        -0.314609
9         0.310828
Target    1.000000
dtype: float64
0         0.061911
1         0.648200
2        -0.293845
3         0.002402
4         0.592591
5        -0.387568
6         0.277449
7         0.574272
8        -0.448803
9        -0.000266
Target    1.000000
dtype: float64
0         0.289361
1         0.306837
2        -0.565776
3         0.018211
4        -0.001650
5        -0.008317
6        -0.318271
7         0.025830
8        -0.001511
9         0.461342
Target    1.000000
dtype: float64
0         0.316292
1         0.223331
2        -0.001817
3         0.423708
4        -0.466166
5        -0.283735
6        -0.212039
7         0.311600
8        -0.292352
9         0.302497
Target    1.000000
dtype: float64
0         0.006351
1        -0.004631
2        -0.331184
3         0.083991
4         0.002227
5        -0.000883
6        -0.123998
7         0.374792
8        -0.087007
9         0.530111
Target    1.000000
dtype: float64
0        -0.278837
1         0.360339
2        -0.407622
3        -0.026460
4        -0.275985
5        -0.007404
6         0.295955
7        -0.290008
8         0.293710
9         0.138187
Target    1.000000
dtype: float64
0         0.005973
1        -0.182802
2        -0.001029
3        -0.000993
4         0.207585
5         0.002144
6         0.298949
7        -0.288891
8        -0.277202
9        -0.203653
Target    1.000000
dtype: float64
0         0.298933
1         0.000461
2        -0.004837
3         0.290285
4        -0.013016
5        -0.003280
6        -0.131817
7         0.048733
8        -0.032910
9         0.002162
Target    1.000000
dtype: float64
0         0.494809
1         0.382098
2         0.549377
3         0.004632
4         0.300572
5        -0.486202
6        -0.581924
7         0.300024
8         0.308240
9        -0.398422
Target    1.000000
dtype: float64
```

Looking at the correlation values alone, we cannot even be sure as of which features are the informative (here 6) and which are the redundant ones (here 4).

In short: there is nothing to be explained here, plus that your finding of "*less than 0.4*" is not accurate.

Similar arguments hold for the mutual information, too.